# My Optiplex 7080 doesn't detect audio devices

Tags: windows-10, speakers, dell-optiplex, win10-fast-startup

My Optiplex 7080 doesn't detect any speaker (even if it is its built-in speaker) after startup. But after a restart, it works fine!

I guess that this problem is caused by fast startup on windows 10. Please help me guys.

Comment: [Disable fast startup](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10)?

Comment: Is it risky for pc?

Comment: No, not risky and you can turn it back on any time you like.  It will slow down boot time a bit though.

Comment: how to turn off?

Comment: The first comment I made had the link.  But it is here: https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

Comment: I did and now it works. But another problem! If I sleep my pc, the same problem happends- no audio.

Comment: OH NO!  I don't know what to do to help you with that.  Either update your question to reflect this or write a new one and perhaps someone else can :)